# Check an input matrix M contains any nonzero diagonal matrix element or not

Tags: matrix, conditional, list-manipulation, procedural-programming, built-in-symbols

Is there a way to easily check an input matrix M contains any nonzero diagonal matrix  element or not?

For example,

- if the M contains any nonzero diagonal matrix element, Output: True.
- if the M contains all zero diagonal matrix elements, Output: False.

Here are some related built-in functions that may help. But I did not find an exact built-in function that I need.

```
DiagonalMatrix[list]
gives a matrix with the elements of list on the leading diagonal, and 0 elsewhere. 

DiagonalMatrix[list,k]
gives a matrix with the elements of list on the k\[Null]^th diagonal.

DiagonalMatrix[list,k,n]
pads with 0s to create an n*n matrix.

Diagonal[m] 
gives the list of elements on the leading diagonal of the matrix m.

Diagonal[m,k]
gives the elements on the k\[Null]^th diagonal of m.
```

Comment: You can used `AnyTrue[Abs[Diagonal[m]], Positive]`

Comment: Another possibility `Norm[Diagonal[m]] > 0` or `Positive[Norm[Diagonal[m]]]`

Comment: Or, `Times @@ Diagonal[m] != 0`.  I am sure there are several other ways, as well.

Comment: like the first option, but i like it because of how close it is to the english phrasing: `AnyTrue[Diagonal[m], Not@*EqualTo[0]]`

Answer (score 3):

```
p = {{-1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {3, 3, 1}};

q = {{0, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {3, 3, 0}};
```

**1.**

Using `AllTrue` with `PossibleZeroQ`

```
! AllTrue[Diagonal @ p, PossibleZeroQ]
```

True

```
! AllTrue[Diagonal @ q, PossibleZeroQ]
```

False

**2.**

Using `ContainsOnly`

```
! ContainsOnly[Diagonal @ p, {0}]
```

True

```
! ContainsOnly[Diagonal @ q, {0}]
```

False

Answer (score 1):

```
p = {{-1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {3, 3, 1}};

q = {{0, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {3, 3, 0}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's examples and using `Position`:

```
f = Length@Position[Diagonal@#, 0] != Length@# &;

f /@ {p, q}

(*{True, False}*)
```